# Taking a spinner position and setting the limit of other spinners to this position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, spinner, android-spinner

I have 2 spinners in my activity. The first one is a normal spinner and the other is inside a recycler. Both spinners contain the same data (for example: they have values from 1 to 10). What I need to do is get the selected position of the 1st spinner and set this position as the max limit for the spinner in recycler.
Example: if we select 5 from spinner 1, the spinners in recycler should contain values from 1 to 5.

Comment: Simple fetch the value from the spinner and pass it in adapter class and set that value to getItemCount(int) method. So that your recyclerview prints only that number of items only .

Comment: well, I need the spinner in recycler to change its maxed limit according to the selected position of the previous spinner, not the recycler count

Comment: so you can use Callback interface and set your limit accordingly by passing the value of recyclerview's spinner

Answer (score 0):

Use live data for this. 
Observe spinner1 list if changes occur update the spinner2 with the new content. You should implement your code as for yiur requirement.Hope it helps little.